# why wp_enqueue_script not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

in plugin development when i try to load js script with wp_enqueue_script it works properly but when i use with wp_enqueue_scripts and add all the thing in a function and then calling a funtion by add_action method it does not work

```
if use wp_enqueue_script it works properly but i use with wp_enqueue_scripts and add_action it does not work please help me to resolve this issue as soon as possible
`below code works properly`

<?php

$path = plugins_url('js/main.js',__FILE__);
$ver = filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__`your text`).'js/main.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-plugin', $path, array(), $ver, true );
?>

`but below code does not work`

<?php
function my_custom_scripts()
{ $path = plugins_url('js/main.js',__FILE__);
   $ver = filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'js/main.js');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-plugin', $path, array(), $ver, true );   
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_custom_scripts');
?>
```

Comment: "it does not work" - can you elaborate? With full PHP and WordPress error reporting turned on, are you getting an error? When you inspect using your browser's network tools, can you see an attempt to load these, but you are getting a 404? Try changing the function to just `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',static function(){die('test');});` to see if your action is even being called in the first place

Comment: hello it does not work mean when ii try first code my custom js file load or add js file to the page but if i use second code with wp_enqueue_scritps function then my custom js file is not load or not add on the page and i also try `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',static function(){die('test');});` but it does not work either. but i found that add_action is not calling the function (my issue is to add my cutom js file to plugin file)